# Select the first div inside a div but only if there are 10 of them

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-selectors

I want to select the first `div.favourite-image` inside `#user-favourites-card` only if there are exactly 10 `div.favourite-image` inside `#user-favourites-card`.

my attempt:

```
#user-favourites-card div.favourite-image:nth-last-child(10):first-child
```

the html to select from:

```
<div _ngcontent-qcm-36="" class="card-noshadow" id="user-favourites-card">
   <div _ngcontent-qcm-36="" class="first-card-header">
      <h6 _ngcontent-qcm-36="">Favourites</h6>
   </div>
   <div _ngcontent-qcm-36="" class="row">
      <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": "[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]"
}--><div _ngcontent-qcm-36="" class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-xl-4">

         <div _ngcontent-qcm-36="" class="favourite-image" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]" style="background-image: url(&quot;result-images/dairy_free_parmesan_alternative_original.jpg&quot;);"></div>
      </div><div _ngcontent-qcm-36="" class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-xl-4">

         <div _ngcontent-qcm-36="" class="favourite-image" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]" style="background-image: url(&quot;result-images/dairy_free_mozzarella_alternative.jpg&quot;);"></div>
      </div><div _ngcontent-qcm-36="" class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-xl-4">

         <div _ngcontent-qcm-36="" class="favourite-image" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]" style="background-image: url(&quot;result-images/dairy_free_tasty_cheese_sauce.jpg&quot;);"></div>
      </div><div _ngcontent-qcm-36="" class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-xl-4">

         <div _ngcontent-qcm-36="" class="favourite-image" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]" style="background-image: url(&quot;result-images/dairy_free_mild_cheese_mix.jpg&quot;);"></div>
      </div><div _ngcontent-qcm-36="" class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-xl-4">

         <div _ngcontent-qcm-36="" class="favourite-image" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]" style="background-image: url(&quot;result-images/sugar_free_dark_chocolate_salted_caramel.png&quot;);"></div>
      </div><div _ngcontent-qcm-36="" class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-xl-4">

         <div _ngcontent-qcm-36="" class="favourite-image" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]" style="background-image: url(&quot;result-images/alpro_drink_for_professional.jpg&quot;);"></div>
      </div><div _ngcontent-qcm-36="" class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-xl-4">

         <div _ngcontent-qcm-36="" class="favourite-image" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]" style="background-image: url(&quot;result-images/alpro_custard.jpg&quot;);"></div>
      </div><div _ngcontent-qcm-36="" class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-xl-4">

         <div _ngcontent-qcm-36="" class="favourite-image" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]" style="background-image: url(&quot;result-images/alpro_coconut_dessert.jpg&quot;);"></div>
      </div><div _ngcontent-qcm-36="" class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-xl-4">

         <div _ngcontent-qcm-36="" class="favourite-image" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]" style="background-image: url(&quot;result-images/alpro_creamy_caramel.jpg&quot;);"></div>
      </div><div _ngcontent-qcm-36="" class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-xl-4">

         <div _ngcontent-qcm-36="" class="favourite-image" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]" style="background-image: url(&quot;result-images/dairy_free_sour_cream_alternative.jpg&quot;);"></div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

aside: I'm wanting to select this exact element to prove there are 10 of them exactly in a Jasmine test.

[This page](http://alistapart.com/article/quantity-queries-for-css) shows how it can be done. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You could clean a little bit the HTML. There is a lot of markdown that is irrelevant to the question and that makes hard to read it. (for instance the images)

Comment: @vals but then someone would say they need to see all of the html as output by the browser.

Comment: @vals is right. Most of markup obstruct us to help you. Also it would be great if you make your code executable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the first element of a `querySelectorAll` node list if its length is exactly 10:

```js
favImg = function() {
  favImgList = document.querySelectorAll('#user-favourites-card div.favourite-image');
  return (favImgList.length == 10) ? favImgList[1] : 'null';
}
console.log(favImg());
```

```html
<div _ngcontent-qcm-36="" class="card-noshadow" id="user-favourites-card">
  <div _ngcontent-qcm-36="" class="first-card-header">
    <h6 _ngcontent-qcm-36="">Favourites</h6>
  </div>
  <div _ngcontent-qcm-36="" class="row">
    <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": "[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]"
}-->
    <div _ngcontent-qcm-36="" class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-xl-4">

      <div _ngcontent-qcm-36="" class="favourite-image" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]" style="background-image: url(&quot;result-images/dairy_free_parmesan_alternative_original.jpg&quot;);"></div>
    </div>
    <div _ngcontent-qcm-36="" class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-xl-4">

      <div _ngcontent-qcm-36="" class="favourite-image" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]" style="background-image: url(&quot;result-images/dairy_free_mozzarella_alternative.jpg&quot;);"></div>
    </div>
    <div _ngcontent-qcm-36="" class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-xl-4">

      <div _ngcontent-qcm-36="" class="favourite-image" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]" style="background-image: url(&quot;result-images/dairy_free_tasty_cheese_sauce.jpg&quot;);"></div>
    </div>
    <div _ngcontent-qcm-36="" class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-xl-4">

      <div _ngcontent-qcm-36="" class="favourite-image" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]" style="background-image: url(&quot;result-images/dairy_free_mild_cheese_mix.jpg&quot;);"></div>
    </div>
    <div _ngcontent-qcm-36="" class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-xl-4">

      <div _ngcontent-qcm-36="" class="favourite-image" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]" style="background-image: url(&quot;result-images/sugar_free_dark_chocolate_salted_caramel.png&quot;);"></div>
    </div>
    <div _ngcontent-qcm-36="" class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-xl-4">

      <div _ngcontent-qcm-36="" class="favourite-image" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]" style="background-image: url(&quot;result-images/alpro_drink_for_professional.jpg&quot;);"></div>
    </div>
    <div _ngcontent-qcm-36="" class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-xl-4">

      <div _ngcontent-qcm-36="" class="favourite-image" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]" style="background-image: url(&quot;result-images/alpro_custard.jpg&quot;);"></div>
    </div>
    <div _ngcontent-qcm-36="" class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-xl-4">

      <div _ngcontent-qcm-36="" class="favourite-image" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]" style="background-image: url(&quot;result-images/alpro_coconut_dessert.jpg&quot;);"></div>
    </div>
    <div _ngcontent-qcm-36="" class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-xl-4">

      <div _ngcontent-qcm-36="" class="favourite-image" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]" style="background-image: url(&quot;result-images/alpro_creamy_caramel.jpg&quot;);"></div>
    </div>
    <div _ngcontent-qcm-36="" class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-xl-4">

      <div _ngcontent-qcm-36="" class="favourite-image" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]" style="background-image: url(&quot;result-images/dairy_free_sour_cream_alternative.jpg&quot;);"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your attempt doesn't correctly select the children as you'd expect. You'll notice that if you try out your selector with just `:first-child` that it doesn't do anything. Each `<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-xl-4"></div>` is the direct child following the `row` class. Any :child like selector requires you to operate on direct parent to child relationships, so your extra divs obscure that.

Instead, you can try this selector:

`#user-favourites-card .row div:nth-last-child(10):first-child .favourite-image`

[As seen in this fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/2s6by681/)

Alternatively, if you add the `favourite-image` class alongside your column classes, you can then stick to the selector you tried earlier.

For example:

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-xl-4 favourite-image">
   ...
</div>
```

[As seen in this fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/2s6by681/1/)